# How to print out the value through classes?

Tags: java

I have problem with printing out the output .

The class methods :

```
public class Account {
    private String name1;
    private String name2;
    private  double grade1;
    private  double grade2;
    private  double grade3;
    private  double average;
    public void setAccount(String a1 ,String a2 ,double b1,double b2,double b3) {

        a1=name1;
        a2=name2; 
        b1=grade1;
        b2=grade2;
        b3=grade3;
    }

    public void setaverage(double k1){
        k1=average;
    }

    public String getAccount(){
        return name1;
    }

    public String getAccount1(){
        return name2;
    }

    public double getAccount2(){
        return grade1;
    }

    public double getAccount3(){
        return grade2;
    }

    public double getAccount4(){
        return grade3;
    }

    public double getaverage(){
        return average=(grade1+grade2+grade3)/3;
    }
}
```

And the main method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

        Account account= new Account();

        System.out.println("Enter the  frist  and last name of student" );

        String na1=in.nextLine();

        account.getAccount(na1);

    } // end main

} // end class AccountTest
```

I have problem in `account.getAccount(na1);`

I tried to print one String to know if the program works .

So how to print the output?

I know that the problem because there's no argument in the get method, but I don't know how to print it, since it's my first time using it .

Comment: `System.out.println(account.getAccount(na1));` ?

Comment: which method do you think should do the printing? main or a method in the Account class? Also, what do you intend getAccount to do? Maybe you need to change the method or write a different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of issues here but don't worry I'll run you through them. There's lots of little things you can do to make your code easier for you and others to understand. Encapsulation seems confusing at first but it starts to make sense pretty fast I found. First off in your constructor you're doing the assignment backwards. I take it your teacher is making you use "getters" and "setters" for every private variable?

Create methods with these signatures:

```
public void setName1(string n1){...}//assigns n1 to name1

public void setName2(String n2){...} //assigns n2 to name2

public void setGrade1(double g1){...} //assigns g1 to grade1

public void setGrade2(double g2){...} //assigns g2 to grade2

public void setGrade3(double g3){...} //assigns gee I wonder.
```

And use them in your constructor:

```
public void setAccount(String n1 ,String n2 ,double g1,double g2,double g3) {

    setName1(n1);
    setName2(n2);
    setGrade1(g1);
    setGrade2(g2);
    setGrade3(g3);


}
```

Next I'd reccommend naming your get* methods in a similar way.

```
 public String getName1(){...}
 public String getName2(){...}
 public double getGrade1(){...}
```

etc.

And, finally, for printing. Once you have all that set up printing to the console is very easy.

```
System.out.println(getName1()); //will print name1 to the console.
```

Read through the code and annotate it to explain (to yourself) what it's doing. It starts to read more and more like english/humanLanguageOfChoice as you go on!

I'm a student too so if any real developers feel like having a dig go ahead.

Comment: Thank  you very much it was  really helpful , but how can I get the inputs from the user , and print them  out

Answer (score 1):

`getAccount` returns the value and it takes no parameters. So write something like:

```
na1 = account.getAccount();
```

Comment: because you don't initailize your variable = didn't give a value to it... Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The method `getAccount(String input)` is not implemented in your code.

This is: `account.getAccount()`.

Comment: the get method  shouldn't have arguments , that is why I  haven't put arguments .

Answer (score 0):

So... Some terminology what you should know and learn...

1. get methods, so called getters have a naming convention first part is get second part is the name of the variable with camelCase so in your case the getters should be `getName1() getName2(), getGrade1(), getGrade2(), getGrade3()` and so on... and not getAccount(), you trick yourself and other develoeprs if you dont use this conventions....
2. set methods, so called setters also have the same naming convention, and in your case the setters should be `setName1(), setName2(), setGrade1(), setGrade2(), setGrade3()` and so on
3. getters supposed to give you back the variables (values) from your class, setters should "set" some value to you instance members (instance or class variables)...
4. From the last point point it clearly devoted that getters are public  getVariable(with no argument) e.g. `public String getName1()` and setters are public setVariable (the argument which will be given to the instance variable) e.g. `public setName1(String name1)`

In your case you don't setted and you dont give a value to your variable, but you want to get it's value, obviously it will have a null value... Is it clear?